# effective user id not changing when setting uid to root

Tags: command-line, permissions, privileges

I'm currently reading a book on programming with C, i got to a part where i got to write a program which will display the real uid and effective uid that the file is being executed on. After compiling the code with gcc, I input the command to see the current uOwner and gOwner `ls- l id_demo` the output is this

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 8629 Sep 21 13:04 id_demo`

i then execute the program it's self this is what i get:

`real uid: 1000 effective uid: 1000` ...so far so good.

I then input a command to change the owner of the file `sudo chown root:root ./id_demo`
the `ls -l` confirms that the owner has been changed to root;

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 8629 Sep 21 13:04 id_demo`

again, executing the program shows `real uid` and `uid` as 1000. The last step after which the `uid` must be 0 is this: `sudo chmod u+s ./uid_demo` but for me they stay as 1000, where in the book the output is clearly show to be this:

`real uid: 1000
effective uid: 0`

any ideas why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

id_demo source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("real uid: %d\n", getuid());
    printf("effective uid: %d\n", geteuid());
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Screen shots

[image]

[image: ls -l testuid]

Comment: Please follow the link to find a detailed solution to this issue [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937775/effective-user-id-does-not-change-after-making-the-file-owned-by-root/18938648?noredirect=1#18938648)

Answer (score 2):

You have changed the suid only for root (`u+s`, when the owner is root). Do `chmod a+s ./uid_demo`.

EDIT after the OP posted the code: works for me.

```
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ cat > test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("real uid: %d\n", getuid());
    printf("effective uid: %d\n", geteuid());
}
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ gcc -o testuid test.c
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ ./testuid 
real uid: 1000
effective uid: 1000
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ sudo chown root:root testuid
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ sudo chmod a+s testuid
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ ./testuid 
real uid: 1000
effective uid: 0
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ ls -l testuid
-rwsrwsr-x 1 root root 8625 Sep 21 14:45 testuid
```

Here is what you can do: (i) do everything from scratch as shown above. If this does not work, you can try to use `strace` to see what is happening.

Comment: i did what you told me but the output of the uid_demo is still showing that the effective uid is 1000. i need it to be 0

Comment: Can you post the program source please? And btw, my first advice was braindead: if you change the owner, the setuid will not work :-)

Comment: haha ok, done :) I really need an answer because the next requires this to work. Please :)

Comment: this is unbelievable, it did not work :( how do i use the strace command?

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko Use these commands: `sudo chown root:root id_test` and `sudo chmod a+s id_test` in exactly this order.

Comment: i did that, it still displays the effective id as 1000 :(

Answer (score 2):

[We've figured it out.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37804/discussion-between-evgeny-danilenko-and-martin-von-wittich) The cause is an `ecryptfs`-mounted home directory. The `mount` output contains the following line:

```
/home/evgeny/.Private on /home/evgeny type ecryptfs
```

That means that the home directory isn't actually part of the root filesystem (that has the necessary `suid` flag), but its own virtual filesystem that apparently doesn't support setuid binaries by default. I have successfully reproduced the issue with a test user that has an encrypted home directory.

It is possible to add the `suid` flag to the ecryptfs with the following command:

```
sudo mount -i -o remount,suid /home/evgeny
```

I'm not certain though how safe that is, nor how to change it permanently so that it would survive reboots.

Comment: Safety depends largely on your environment, so I can't comment.  If it's your workstation and you're the only regular user, it shouldn't be a problem.  To make the change permanent, add replace "defaults" with "suid" in the line describing the mount in /etc/fstab.

Comment: These `.Private` mounts are mounted automatically during login, and aren't listed in `/etc/fstab`.