# How to permit SUID

Tags: permissions, command-line, privileges

I need to permit suid for my user account on my ubuntu 13.04.

According to the `mount` command the bit flag for my account is nosuid.
how do i change it to suid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your system have a separate `/home` partition? if so it's possible that is mounted with the `nosuid` for good reasons. If this is just a test, then rather than making any persistent changes to your mount options in /etc/fstab, it should be possible to remount the partition temporarily with the suid enabled using

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,suid /home
```

For example (since my home partition is not regularly mounted `nosuid` I'll do that first, for the sake of illustration):

```
$ ls -l id_demo
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 7394 Sep 21 08:52 id_demo
$ 
$ sudo mount -o remount,nosuid /home
$ ./id_demo
real uid: 1006
effective uid: 1006
```

Then testing again after remounting with option `suid`

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,suid /home
$ ./id_demo
real uid: 1006
effective uid: 0
```

Note that `chmod u+s` should be sufficient for your test (`chmod a+s` should not be necessary).

Comment: thank you for your reply. no i did not partition my home and usr directories when i installed ubuntu 13.04. I followed your step regardless but got this error `mount: can't find /home in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
`

Comment: Well if you don't have a separate `/home` partition, then in principle it should be possible to remount the whole (root) filesystem in the same way i.e. `mount -o remount,suid /` but I am reluctant to suggest you try it since I don't know if doing so might have other (undesirable) consequences - let's see if someone more knowledgeable posts a better answer.

Comment: thank you for the replies :) we have solved the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937775/effective-user-id-does-not-change-after-making-the-file-owned-by-root/18938648?noredirect=1#18938648)

Answer (score 0):

The "SUID/NOSUID" that `mount` tells you about isn't about your "user account". See  `man mount`.  It's a security feature, and tells the system to recognize/ignore setuid executables on the mounted medium. When a setuid executable is executed, from a disk mounted with SUID, it will run with the UID of the owner of the executable, rather than running with your UID.

In short, don't worry about it

If you want to worry about it, the SUID/NOSUID bit comes from `/etc/fstab` (see `man -k fstab;man 5 fstab`, and is applied at mount time (for that device).

Comment: i need to worry about it because [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348282/effective-user-id-not-changing-when-setting-uid-to-root)